# Two if statements and actions in one script?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to write a script that will monitor input from both a PIR sensor as well as a switch. The plan is that the sensor will keep running and only send a capture from an attached webcam if it detects motion. The switch will send a capture if it is activated. Both will send the captures through e-mail. Here is the code.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)         #Read output from PIR motion sensor
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)         #LED output pin
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)



while True:

       input_state = GPIO.input(26)

       i=GPIO.input(17)

       if input_state == False:
                    print('DING DONG')
            os.system("python buzztest.py")
                    #GPIO.output(4, 0)  #Turn OFF LED
                #GPIO.output(4, 0)  #Turn ON LED
                #time.sleep(1)
                #GPIO.output(4, 0)  #Turn OFF LED
                #os.system("python doorbellpost.py")
            os.system("fswebcam -r 640x480 --no-banner /root/Desktop/codes/ringcap/ringcap.jpg")
            os.system("python mailpic.py")
                time.sleep(1)


   if i==0:                 
   #When output from motion sensor is LOW
         print "No intruders detected",i
         #GPIO.output(4, 0)  #Turn OFF LED
         time.sleep(2)
   elif i==1:               #When output from motion sensor is HIGH
         print "Intruder detected!",i
         #GPIO.output(4, 1)  #Turn ON LED
             os.system("fswebcam -r 640x480 --no-banner /root/Desktop/codes/motioncap/motcap.jpg")
         os.system("python motmail.py") 
         time.sleep(2)       


GPIO.cleanup()
```

The script also calls other scripts, namely separate email scripts for the respective captures for the doorbell and motion sensor. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT. Sorry I forgot about the question. So is there another way to implement this? Two if statements running at once? When I run the program the sensor statement runs, but activating the switch has some issues, namely the 'Ding dong' doesn't activate sometimes.

Comment: What's the question? [ask]

Comment: Edited. I forgot about the question my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multiprocessing` module of python that help to run two code simultaneously may improve your performance.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)         #Read output from PIR motion sensor
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)         #LED output pin
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def func1():
  while True:
        #first if statement

def func2():
   while True:
         #Second if Statement


if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=func2)
  p2.start()
```